# Common terminology for "blessing" and "curse"?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary

I'm doing a certain something that requires identifying a property of some certain (fictional) thing as either "Blessed", "Cursed", or "Neither".  What's the common term for "Blessing" or "Cursed", if any?

In a thesaurus, the only common link I found between the two was that "Blessing" can mean "Benediction", and "Curse" can mean "Malediction", so "*_*_-diction" might be the common etymological denominator... but I'm still clueless as to where to go from there.

Any ideas?

Comment: The programming wasn't the main point anyway, but I censored any extraneous details not pertaining to the core of the question into something vague and cloudy so it hopefully won't get deleted.

Comment: ***Superstition***

Comment: I agree it'd be "Superstition" in real life.  But not so in a fantasy RPG setting.

Comment: Sometimes there just isn't a word for the common superset (hypernym). It's either a blessing or a curse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a role-playing game, one might say that a blessing and a curse are both types of *charm*. That is, something might be charmed with a blessing or charmed with a curse.

> **charm<sup>3</sup>** An object, act, or saying believed to have magic power
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/charm)

In a programming context, `isBlessed` would do, although `isCharmed` would also work: value `1` for blessed, `-1` for cursed and `0` for neither.